# Is there any statistical method to proof if the method is suitable or not

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-statistics, remote-sensing, accuracy, geostatistical-analyst

I have recently done a phenological study using threshold method from MODIS NDVI images. But I'm suffered that I don't have any situ observation (ground truth) data to do validation. Is there any statistical method to validate that this method is suitable for remote sensing based phenological study without ground truth data.

Phenology is the study of periodic plant life cycle events (onset of green-up, maturity, offset of green-up etc) and how these are influenced by seasonal and interannual variations in climate, as well as habitat factors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to provide much more detail about what you have done and where you are stuck.  For example, I suspect "phonological" is a term that you will need to provide a definition for or link to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about nothing specifically related to GIS

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  I have voted to reopen this question because it now clearly falls within the scope of this site.  Are you interested in doing an accuracy assessment to determine the accuracy of the threshold product.  Are you able to accurately hand digitize vegetation within a GIS?

Comment: This question would fit into the suggested StackExchange Geoscience: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/geoscience

Furthermore, there is no statistical method that can validate/ground truth/ground control your method. What you could do though is to relate your results to other studies, by showing that your results compare well to those. You could do this using accuracy assessment, i.e. calculate the Kappa value.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. @Aaron my study area is whole territory of Russia which is really big area. It would be tremendous work if I digitize vegetation.

Comment: One approach would be to create random sample points throughout your study area and manually classify the raster at these points.  Then use these manually classified points as the basis for your accuracy assessment.